# scan audio file in context.getExternalFilesDir

Tags: android

I record a music and save as .amr in dir

```
File parent = context.getExternalFilesDir(null).
File dir = new File(parent , "voice");
if(!dir.exists()){
    dir.mkdirs();
}
```

I want to obtain the lenght of the audio.So I use

```
MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(context,
                    new String[]{file.getAbsolutePath()}, new String[]{"audio/amr"} ,
                    new OnScanCompletedListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                            LogUtil.w("TAG" , "path = "+path);
                            LogUtil.w("TAG" , "uri = "+uri);

                        }
                    }
            );
```

however , the log shows

```
04-16 16:29:53.893  24364-25296/com.wxy.gudong.client.debug W/TAG﹕ path = /storage/sdcard/Android/data/com.wxy.gudong.client.debug/files/voice/bbb664e8-6ddf-47d6-87ed-cf9867e77a75audio.amr
04-16 16:29:53.893  24364-25296/com.wxy.gudong.client.debug W/TAG﹕ uri = content://media/external/file/3858
```

scan success but scanner treated the audio as a file , not an audio.
And I can not obtain the audio information by

```
Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            null, MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA + "=?",
            new String[]{file.getAbsolutePath()},
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.DEFAULT_SORT_ORDER);
```

Why the audio file in the dir not be treated as an audio.And How should I do to get the audio length.

Thank you!